# Getting error after updating xcode 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have updated the xcode 5.0 to 5.1 today. I run the existed project but getting the error now. I had no issues while running that project on 5.0 version. The error is below :

```
ld: library not found for -lIOKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please someone help.

I re-added the frameworks but now I get another error which is below

```
ld: 62 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the framework?

Comment: try cleaning the project, go to lib->developers->xcode->derivedData and delete it

Comment: how to go to lib->developers->xcode->derivedData?

Comment: @sbarow - I edited the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your project configuration -> Build Settings -> Architechtures -> Valid architectures

Check if you've got the armv7s label duplicated.

You can also try to set to YES the Build Architechtures Only.

[image]

Comment: I have "Build Architectures Only" set to YES and there is "armv7s" value in Valid Architectures. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, have a look at Target->Build phases->complie sources and check if you've got duplicated classes there.

Comment: Checked, no duplicate files in compile sources either but still same error.

Comment: Can you also check if you imported a .m file instead of a .h file accidentally? This caused me a headache some time ago

Comment: I have checked this already, no .m file imported by mistake. Just to let you know, I have added my static library in this project. Do you think there is problem due to this.

Comment: Ok, this can also happen when you have cycles with your imports. Check if you import a header (let's call it H1) in your static library and then you import your library in H1

Comment: Ok, runnning out of ideas here... check for duplicate frameworks in your Build Phases > Link Binary With Library

Comment: You can also try to do a complete clean of your project: Option + Command + Shift + k, restart xCode and try again

Comment: @Funny did you find a solution for this issue? I'm getting the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Please Check:- goto build setting, writing in search bar "GCC", check weather compiler is setup or not (LLMV 5.xx).